# How to select / copy text from "Graphics" string element in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a chat window and have created tiles for messages.

[image]

I have a problem because the text in tiles draws using the `DrawString` method and I`m not really sure if there is any such possibility that this text can be copied? How can it enable the user to select and copy text? Below is part of the source code.

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    var graphics = e.Graphics;
    ...
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
    {
         if (_BoxPosition == BoxPositionEnum.Left)
         {
             graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, new Rectangle(20 , Height / 2, renderWidth - 5, Height / 2 - 5));
         }
         else
         {
             StringFormat format = new StringFormat()
             {
                  LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                  Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
             };
             graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush,
                            new Rectangle(_mc.BoxIndent - 10 , Height / 2, renderWidth - 5, Height / 2 - 5),format);
         }
}
```

Comment: If you are not using standard controls that allow for text select, like `TextBox` or `RichTextBox`, then you will need to write those features yourself.  The computer doesn't do anything you don't tell it to.

Comment: I decided to do it this way because I couldn't control the text wrapping and box matching with a plain `TextBox` during resize. I guess I can't copy something that has been drawn. The question is how can I achieve it? ;p

Comment: Just a suggestion. How about replacing the chat box with something like [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-overview) or [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) so you can visualize the contents in much better ways. Or maybe host a WPF [FormatedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext?view=netframework-4.8) object. You have much better alternatives.

Comment: You could present all that using an owner drawn ListView control. BUT, I agree with JQSOFT here. WinForms is not (really not, when you have a hard time figuring out basic operations on text layout) the platform you want to use for this kind of projects. IMO, move the Project to WPF.

Comment: Just take a look at the tools available in [Documents in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/documents-in-wpf), [Flow Content elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/flow-content) and [Typography in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/typography-in-wpf)

Comment: You need to store the text somewhere. You can't really extract it from the pixels. But, since you need to be able to redraw it anyway, you must already do that. So where exactly do you draw on and where does the paint event get the text from???

Answer (score -1):

- For simple: just use `TextBox` or `RichTextBox` and set `ReadOnly = true` and color as what you want.
- For more advanced: create your own message box user control, and you can do many thing with it (react, select all, ...).
  Here the tutorial for create your own user control: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/user-control-in-C-Sharp/